# Why do my pointer change itself automatically?

Tags: c++

```
struct t{
    int a;
    t(int i){
        a = i;
    }
};

void test(t**& ppT){
    t *pT = (t*)malloc(sizeof(t));
    pT->a = 100;//works

    t *pT = new t(100);//doesn't work

    ppT = &pT;
}
```

I have a struct named *t*, and a function called *test*.

In main(), I have

```
t **ppT = NULL;
test(ppT);
cout << ppT << " " << *ppT << endl;
cout << ppT << " " << *ppT << endl;
```

If I use malloc in *test*, it works.
However, if I use new in *test*, it will show me

```
0049FCC8 0074C378
0049FCC8 CCCCCCCC
```

What's the problem? Furthermore, I use Visual Studio 2013 as my compiler.

Comment: This looks dangerously close to [Three Star Programming](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ThreeStarProgrammer)

Answer (score 6):

Because in the `test` function the variable `pT` is local, and it will go out of scope once the function returns. The pointer to it you get with `&pT` will become invalid once you return from the function, and attempting to use it will lead to *undefined behavior*.

And that's only *half* the problem, the other is that you pass a null pointer to the function, and dereference it inside the function. When you emulate pass by reference (what you do by using a pointer to a pointer) you need to use the address-of operator on a pointer, like

```
t* pA = 0;
test(&pT);
```

This also brings into scope the question why you use a reference to a pointer-to-pointer, instead of just simply a reference to a pointer, like

```
void test(t*& pT);
...
t* pT = nullptr;
test(pT);
```